# Default profile picture with if condition

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I searched a lot on the internet how to add default profile picture but I found nothing:

```
<td><img class="image" src="image/<?php echo $contact['avatar']?>"></td>
```

I have use this to upload image by user choice but I don't know if there is no picture how to add default picture.

Comment: Do have any facility store img name or path?

Comment: A little bit more information please. What have you tried?

Comment: <td><img class="image" src="image/<?php echo $contact['avatar']?>"></td>

Comment: i used this for a uploading picture by user choice and it will be saved in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<img src="<?php if(file_exists($imgPath){ echo $imgPath; }else{ echo "default_image_path"; } ?>"/>
```

Comment: i don't where to add it its been 10 days im working in a project i have created 9 php file and one css generlly its web site for a enterprise that they give us in university its for those who register new emploi with thier database in the adding contact if the employ doesnt upload his it automaticly should add default pic i should write the code in the which file

Answer (score 0):

Put a `unknown` kind of image in your image folder, and when rendering the user's image put a check like:

```
if( condition )  // condition to check if user uploaded an image or not
{
    // show the user uploaded image here
}
else
{
    // show the unknown image here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try below code

```
<img src="<?php if($imgPath !== '') echo $imgPath; else echo $noPicPath;?>"/>
```

Thanks 
 
Hope! This will help you

Answer (score 0):

Simply try setting your profile image div's "background-image" property to the image you want in CSS.

Something like this,

**HTML**

```
<div id="profile-picture"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#profile-picture{
  background-image: 'img/src';
}
```

PS Please try to post your code which was not working when you tried instead of explaining it in words.

Hope it helps, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($imgPath != ''){ ?>
    <img src="<?php  echo $imgPath;?>">
<?php }else{ ?>
    <img src="<?php  echo $defaultimgPath;?>">
<?php }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your php version under 7 use ternary operator

```
<img src="<?=(!empty($uploadedPhoto)? $uploadedPhoto : $defaultPhoto);?>" />
```

if php version over 7 use null coalescing operator

```
<img src="<?=$uploadedPhoto ??  $defaultPhoto ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 <img src="<?php if($imgPath != '') echo $imgPath; else echo $noPicPath;?>"/>
```